# how to select the sentence only between the symbols in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep the word between the symbols as shown below in an array.

`my $string = "<hi how r u><<<what is your name>>><what is your age><<<hi how r u>>><this is idiot><<<iam fine>>>";`

i need to grep as

```
@str = ("what is yourname","hi how r u","iam fine");
@str1 = ("hi how r u","what is your age","this is idiot")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=<<<)([\w ]+)(?=>>>)|([\w ]+)
```

Try this.Group 1 will be your first set and group 2 the second.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/8

Comment: @idiotonperl it is working.You can check d demo.What error you get